# How to translate 'serve' in these sentences?

Tags: translation, usage

I'm translating some programming documentation. I know 'serve' can be translated to 服务/提供. But in the sentences below, it sounds a bit weird in Chinese. So, what are the right and elegant translations of 'serve' in the sentences below? Thanks!

1. How do I **serve** the static files in deployment?
2. ...setting up your server to **serve** this address.
3. ...to ensure newer Bootstrap versions are **served**.

Answer (score 1):

serve:

1. 在开发过程中如何加载静态文件? 开发过程中静态文件如何管理？
2. 设置好你的服务器来为这个地址提供服务
3. 确保你正在使用新版本的 Bootstrap

Comment: Is it better to translate the last sentence to '确保Bootstrap的新版本被加载' ?